# Getting a value from a dropdown data attribute and passing it to a input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to pass values that i have stored in a multiple dropdown list to relevant input fields on select. I have gotten it to work to a certain extent but i can't get it to work when the input field and the select drop down is **not** under the parent div.

**Current working code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select2').select2();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.material-price').change(function() {
    var materialValue = $(this).select2().find(":selected").data("price");
    $(this).parent('.row').find('.material-total').val(materialValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <select class="material-price select2">
        <option value="100" value="10">Material A</option>
        <option data-price="400" value="20>">Material B</option>
        <option data-price="500" value="30">Material C</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="material-total" readonly />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code i'm trying to fix**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class='col-md-2 nopadding'>
    <div class='form-group nomarg'>
      <select class="material-pricex select2">
        <option data-price="100" value="10">Material A</option>
        <option data-price="400" value="20>">Material B</option>
        <option data-price="500" value="30">Material C</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='col-md-1 nopadding'>
    <div class='form-group nomarg'>
       <input type='number' id="total" name="total" min='0' class='form-control'>
    </div>
  </div>     
</div>
```

How can I get data-price value selected on `material-pricex` to pass it to the "total" input field?

Comment: `$('#total').val(materialValue);` keep it simple use ID selector to set value

Comment: @Satpal Yea i can do with single a row. But in my case i have multiple rows. What's the best way to target and get the value? I have duplicate rows in my scenario with the same ID and class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your implantation was usage of [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) which only tragets the direct parent element of the selected element, thus your code didn't worked.

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)/[`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) to traverse up-to common ancestor then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the desired element.

```
$(this).closest('.row').find('.material-total').val(materialValue);
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much. :) I'm kinda new to all of this so i'm tampering around. Thanks again!